# Delete a recreate a docker container using the same volume

Tags: docker

I have a redis docker container (ran using --appendonly yes). When I delete the container and start a new one, it does not use the same volume. How can I manage to start a new redis container with the previous volume from the defunct container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `--volumes-from defunct-container` parameter. That only works when you did not yet delete the defunct container.